# How to remove logout button title when we get facebook user details in ios

Tags: ios, swift

Hi aim beginner in Ios and in my project i am adding face-book login facility for users

And when users click login button  enter with proper user id and passwords then  it's asking permission like below image then i am clicking "OK" button then it's calling below method

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                          user:(id)user {

and it's redirected to my Mainviewcontroller
[image]

and there login button title showing "logout" like below light gray color image and then it's redirected to another page
But i don't want to show that logout button when we call that above delegate method and i want show that title like "log in with face-book" can some help me please

[image]

### my code is below:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "HomeViewController1.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()
{
    FBLoginView *loginview;
    UILabel * loginLabel;
}

@end

@implementation HomeViewController
@synthesize fblogin;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc]init];
    loginview.frame = CGRectMake(10, 95, 271, 37);
    loginview.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];

    for (id obj in loginview.subviews)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton * loginButton =  obj;
            UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImg.png"];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
             loginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            loginLabel =  obj;
            loginLabel.text = @"Log in with Facebook";
            loginLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 271, 37);
       }
    }

    loginview.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginview];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

// This method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

     NSLog(@"User Id : %@",user.id);
     NSLog(@"User Name : %@",user.name);

    HomeViewController1 * home1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController1"];
    [self presentViewController:home1 animated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```

Comment: you can use your custom button instead of using facebook button, It will work for sure

Answer (score -2):

If get information, `button.hidden = true`

Comment: i just do it in my project, and it works! why to vote me down? or any better answer? I want to know it, too. Thanks. @Kirsteins